# How are vertices connected in a Johnson graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I understand the vertices of a Johnson graph are a k-element subset of an n-element set.

Example:
N = 4, K = 2

$\left(\frac{4}{2}\right)$ = 6

The 6 vertices are: {1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4}.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph), "two vertices are adjacent when they meet in a (k-1)-element set". Could somebody explain what that means?

**My attempt:**
In the example the (k-1) element set would be a set of 2-1 = 1 element, but in that case I do not understand how two vertices can meet in a set with a single element. I also tried drawing 6 vertices, marking them with a subset each and connecting the vertices (subsets) containing one of the same elements, but could not create the (4,2) Johnson graph drawn on [WolframAlpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JohnsonGraph.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JohnsonGraph.html) has a clearer explanation -- the $(n, k)$ Johnson graph labels each of its vertices after all the size-$k$ subsets of $\{1 \dots n\}$, and vertex $a$ is connected to vertex $b$ iff their intersection contains $k-1$ elements.

So in your example above, there would be a edge between the vertices $\{1, 2\}$ and $\{1, 3\}$ (since their intersection $\{1\}$ is of size $k - 1 = 1$), but not the vertices $\{2, 4\}$ and $\{1, 3\}$.

Wikipedia's use of "meet" is incredibly confusing here.